# Formula in name of Theorem

Tags: math-mode, theorems

I want to write in "math mode" in the name of the Theorem.

I wrote at the beginning

```
\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}{20pt}{14pt}{\itshape}{0pt}{\bfseries}{.}{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}{}

\theoremstyle{mytheorem}

\newtheorem{satz}{Theorem}[section]
```

Everything work's fine if I write

```
\begin{satz}[Name]
...
\end{satz}
```

But it's not possible to use the math-mode in the name like

```
\begin{satz}[Theorem in $C[0,1]$]
```

Is there a possibility to use "formulas" in the name of Theorems?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Which theorem package are you using?

Comment: You may get away with `\begin{satz}[{Theorem in $C[0,1]$}]`.  The `]` in your interval is confusing the LaTeX parsing of the optional argument.

Answer (score 2):

square bracket treated as the Theorem's subheading, so please follow the suggested method:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}{20pt}{14pt}{\itshape}{0pt}{\bfseries}{.}{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}{}

\theoremstyle{mytheorem}

\newtheorem{satz}{Theorem}[section]

\def\lbrack{[}
\def\rbrack{]}

\begin{document}

\begin{satz}[Name]
Test
\end{satz}

\begin{satz}[Theorem in $C\lbrack 0,1\rbrack$]
Test
\end{satz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or just `{$C[0,1]$}`